# Rx swift merge and enum

Tags: swift, rx-swift

iam news to rx swift and i really need help for this..
Firstly i have this enum called Cable

```
enum Cable {
case iphone
case android
case typec

func setProperty() -> (String, String, UIImage, UIImage) {

    switch self {
    case .iphone:
        return ("Apple line"  , "1" , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_tiv_iphone") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_t_iphone"))
    case .android:
        return ("Android line", "2" , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_tiv_android") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_t_android"))
    case .typec:
        return ("Type-C line" , "3" , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_tiv_typec") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_t_typec"))
    }
 }

}
```

and I have 3 button we will call it `iphone` button, `android` button and `typec` button and in this code im trying to bind it using rx

```
private func bindActions() {
let tapStream = Observable.of(
              appleBtn.rx.tap.map  ({Cable.iphone.setProperty()}),
              androidBtn.rx.tap.map({Cable.android.setProperty()}),
              typeCBtn.rx.tap.map  ({Cable.typec.setProperty()}))
.merge()

tapStream.map({ name, type, image1, image2 in localized("label.powerBank") + name })
    .do(onNext: {[weak self] type in
     self?.borrowBtn.isEnabled = true})
    .bind(to: lineName)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

tapStream.map({ name, type, image1, image2 in type})
    .bind(to: cableType)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

tapStream.map({ name, type, image1, image2 in image1})
    .bind(to: powerBankImage.rx.image)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

tapStream.map({ name, type, image1, image2 in image2})
    .bind(to: cableImage.rx.image)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

When applebtn, androidBtn, typeCbtn map the value using the enum func they return 4 value so that i can use it in other stream. The problem is that i dont like how thing are now. I think ts should be the enum should has 4 func that return for its respective value for example setTitle func return the "Apple Line" (i havent created the func yet). But how i can set this func to its stream for example if it bind to lineName the map should call the setTitle func ? Since map only return 1 value which is the name when merge. Please help i kinda lost

Comment: Firstly you shouldn’t name that func “set”. It returns value... Please read naming convention for swift language. In your case I think you could use properties rather than func - title, type, powerBankImage, cableImage

Comment: @TomaszPikć yes i already fixed it in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i learn more about rx and enum finally found the answer i looking for 
so the enum structure become something like this.

```
enum Cable{
case iphone
case android
case typec

func cableName() -> (String){

    switch self {
    case .iphone:
        return ("Apple line")
    case .android:
        return ("Android line")
    case .typec:
        return ("Type-C line")
    }
}

func cableType() -> (String){

    switch self {
    case .iphone:
        return ("1")
    case .android:
        return ("2")
    case .typec:
        return ("3")
    }
}

func powerBankImage() -> (UIImage) {

    switch self {
    case .iphone:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_tiv_iphone")
    case .android:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_tiv_android")
    case .typec:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_tiv_typec")
    }
}

func cableImage() -> (UIImage){

    switch self {
    case .iphone:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_t_iphone")
    case .android:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_t_android")
    case .typec:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_borrow_t_typec")
    }
}
}
```

and after that you only need to tuple the selected func

```
 tapStream.map({ $0.cableName()})
    .map({name in localized("label.powerBank") + name})
    .bind(to: lineName)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```